# Best practices for _id in PouchDB / CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

**TL;DR:  If one chooses to use fields like `address` and `lastname` in the `_id` of a document, how do you handle updates to `address` and `lastname` in a way that scales in a multi-device, sometimes offline environment.**

---

I am looking for best practices when using fields in a document's `_id` that may change in the future. For example, `address` and/or `lastname`. Not only can a customer's address change, but what if a user entered the wrong address by mistake? What if the mistake was not found until after the document has been replicated across devices and updated on more than one device?

Is there a way to handle updates to `_id`s? For example, creating an entirely new document with a new `_id` and removing the old one? But does that scale in a multi-device, sometimes offline world?

For example:

```
{
  "_id": "Jane-Smith",
  "address": "44 street, Boston, MA 93999",
  "telephone": "8888888888"
}
```

To handle the case that there are multiple customers with the same name, would it make sense to use add something to the customer name?

```
{
  "_id": "Jane-Smith-7ae78c",
  "address": "44 street, Boston, MA 93999",
  "telephone": "8888888888"
}
```

Pros:

1. Saves space
2. Since `_id` is the primary key, searches using `_id` are faster

Cons:

1. What if properties used in `_id` change? Searches would be performed on stale data. If you create a new document with the updated `_id`, what are the implementations across synced databases that may have made offline changes?

**Update:**

This article was helpful:

https://davidcaylor.com/2012/05/26/can-i-see-your-id-please-the-importance-of-couchdb-record-ids/

I did not realize that `_ids` could be composed of `address` **and** `lastname`. **However, what if a customer's address and/or name changes?**

I am trying to wrap my head around the right way to store `customer` data in PouchDB / CouchDB.

Comment: Is it necessary to use fields like `adress` or `lastname` in your `_id`? Why not just use a GUID? This should prevent collisions and changing values as you mentioned. Saving space and higher performance is important, but keep in mind that _premature optimization is the root of all evil_.

Comment: This is exactly my question.  I'm leaning towards the default GUID approach  at the moment.  However, I'm also curious if it is considered a good practice to use fields in `_id`s that may change over time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your id contains information that is frequently changing, then it's best just not to store that information in the id. The optimization to pack as much user information as possible into ids is a good one, but it breaks down if that information ever changes, because once the id changes you can't really track changes to that document anymore because it effectively becomes a new document.

In your case you should probably make the id something else (random, even) and then use mapreduce/pouchdb-find for querying.